# Using echo = {number} removes code toggles in R Notebooks

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, rnotebook

So if I have some code, such as:

````
---
title: "Data Exploration"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r, echo = 2}
data("mtcars")
summary(mtcars$mpg)
```
````

then I would expect only the 2nd line, i.e. `summary(mtcars$mpg)` to show in my previewed document. But what it actually does is remove all code from my previewed document and removes the show/hide code toggle button. Any idea how I can show certain lines whilst keeping the toggle button?

Comment: With `code_folding : show` and rmarkdown v1.8 your code works as expected. Can you post the whole rmarkdown file?

Comment: I've added the YAML, this is literally it. I'm on rmarkdown v1.10

Comment: `code_folding: show` isn't exactly what I want. Whilst it "hides" the code, it doesn't remove it from the preview completely. I want only the second line, i.e. the `summary()` to be included in the document

Answer (score 0):

I would have added this as a comment, but I do not have that capability yet. This seems like it might be a bug. It works fine in the other document types. If you need to use a notebook the not so elegant work around would be to just use two chunks.

Comment: Yeah I ended up separating it out into two separate chunks but `include = FALSE` doesn't work for the one I want to hide unfortunately.

Comment: Use `echo = FALSE` in the chunk that you want to exclude. That worked for me.

Comment: This does work, it's just a shame that `echo = -1` doesn't. I feel it may be a bug.

Comment: Yea, same. Maybe open an issue on the github page.